# scheduleOnce crash in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I try to delete a target with delay time, and I code like this

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

  targetsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray array] init]; 
  for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {// here _targets is NSMutableArray
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
        [targetsToRemove addObject:target];
    }
  }
  [self scheduleOnce:@selector(delayToDelete) delay:0.3];
}
```

the delay delete code is

```
-(void)delayToDelete
{
 for (CCSprite *target in targetsToRemove) { //it will crash at this line, when I run
    if (target.tag == 1) {
        CCLOG(@"do something");

    }
    else {
        CCLOG(@"do nothing");
    }
 }
}
```

if I don't use '[self scheduleOnce:@selector(delayToDelete) delay:0.3];', just use [self delayToDelete], it will run well, so what the problem with this code? Thanks

Comment: What is your stack trace?

Comment: @JamesWebster Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=x0x)

Comment: Enable zombie objects. Most likely targetsToRemove was deallocated and if you aren't using ARC this will crash.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add `target` to `targetsToRemove`, a reference to an object in `_target` is being added to `targetsToRemove`. So when `_target` is deallocated so is the object you have added `targetsToRemove`

Try  `[targetsToRemove addObject:[target Copy]];`

If that works then `_target` is being deallocated.

Comment: move `targetsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray array] init];` out of `(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. Make `targetsToRemove`  global